# What engine evaluation does the average randomly generated legal position have?

Tags: engines, statistics

Would it be accurate to expect a random legal position to tend to evaluate to a white advantage? How does the distribution of evaluations look like?

Comment: On those assumptions, it would probably evaluate to the benefit of the side the engine is playing: many  engines have a contempt-factor to bias their own side.

Comment: The side to move would have the advantage on average.  Is side to move part of randomization?

Comment: @MichaelWest Yes

Answer (score 4):

Given a legal position, the same position with colors swapped (and rows mirrored) is legal, apart from a very small number of exceptions like the position after `1.a3`. So the average evaluation must be very close to 0.

Comment: Actually, small correction: the position after `1.e4` is legal even with colors swapped because black can lose a tempo with the queen or bishop: `1.Nf3 e5 2. Ng1 Be7 3. Nf3 Bd6 4. Ng1 Bf8`. An example of a legal position that becomes illegal after swapping colors is the one after `1. a3`, since one cannot lose tempi moving just the rook and knight.